# How do you add the resolution icon to the top menu bar on the Macbook Pro (retina)

Tags: macbook-pro

I just got a MacBook pro retina to replace my old Macbook Pro.
I no longer see the screen resolution icon at the top icon bar, (where the Wifi, audio, Backup, etc Icons reside)

Do you know how to add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method built-in to Mavericks (the OS you are likely using on a new Retina MacBook Pro). However, there are 3rd party utilities to add this functionality.

Try [QuickRes](http://www.quickresapp.com). You may want the paid version rather than the free in order to select all the resolutions your machine offers...